# Multiple png files to multiple ico files: Strange behavior

Tags: windows, imagemagick

There are 2 png images in a directory: `a.png` and `b.png`. I'm trying to convert them to `a.ico` and `b.ico` with a single command.

Doesn't work as I want, only `a.ico` is created:

```
magick.exe *.png -define icon:auto-resize="256,128,96,64,48,32,16" -set filename:f %t %[filename:f].ico
```

However, the same approach works fine when I convert the images from PNG to JPG:

```
magick.exe *.png -set filename:f %t %[filename:f].jpg
```

What's wrong here?

Comment: Have a look here... https://stackoverflow.com/a/61015771/2836621 or use `magick mogrify -format ico -define icon:auto-resize="256,128,96,64,48,32,16" *.png`

Comment: @MarkSetchell It was necessary to use `convert` in my case, not `mogrify`, and your solution with `+adjust` works perfectly. Thanks.